# Ant & Concordion: Classpath issue

Tags: ant, junit, classpath, concordion

I'm new to Ant/Concordion, and my first question on Stack Overflow so hope you'll be gentle.

Trying to setup an Ant task to automatically run my Concordion Acceptance Tests and generate a summary/overview/index html page that lists what tests passed, failed, etc.

I'm using [Concordion Ant Task](http://badrobot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bad.robot/concordion-ant-task/manual/Overview.html) but having an issue where I believe my classpath is incorrect.

The package structure is mirrored test/java/spec & test/resources/spec as the seperation between the fixtures and the specifications.

Here is my build.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Bowling" default="run.acceptance.tests">
    <path id="dependencies">
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="concordion-ant-task-*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="freemarker*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="lib" includes="junit*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="junit" 
        classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask" />
    <taskdef name="generate-test-overview"    
        classname="bad.robot.concordion.ant.GenerateTestOverviewTask" 
        classpathref="dependencies"/>

    <target name="check.dependencies"
        unless="classpath.as.supplied.by.maven">
        <!--  <fail message="Missing dependencies, run using Maven instead (*blush*) or switch to use classpathref='dependencies'"/>-->
    </target>

    <target name="generate-overview"
        depends="check.dependencies">
        <generate-test-overview 
            template="src\test\resources\spec\bowlingGame\Overview.ftl"      
            output="src\test\resources\spec\bowlingGame\Overview.html">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}\src\test\resources\spec\bowlingGame\">
                <include name="**/*.html"/>
                <exclude name="**/Overview.html" />
                <exclude name="**/BowlingGame.html" />
            </fileset>
        </generate-test-overview>
    </target>

    <echo message="${basedir}" />

    <target name="run.acceptance.tests"
        depends="generate-overview">
        <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="yes">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${basedir}"/>
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="plain"/>
            <test name="Overview"/> <!-- corresponding java fixture, must match the overview page generated -->
        </junit>
    </target>  
</project>
```

Here is the ant output.

```
        Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
    Using C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\Bowling\ant.log file as build log.
Buildfile: C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\Bowling\build.xml
parsing buildfile C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\Bowling\build.xml with URI = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/gafitzgerald/training/Bowling/build.xml
Project base dir set to: C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\Bowling
[antlib:org.apache.tools.ant] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
     [echo] C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\Bowling
Build sequence for target(s) `run.acceptance.tests' is [check.dependencies, generate-overview, run.acceptance.tests]
Complete build sequence is [check.dependencies, generate-overview, run.acceptance.tests, ]
check.dependencies:
generate-overview:
[generate-test-overview] looking for files in C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\Bowling\src\test\resources\spec\bowlingGame...
[generate-test-overview]    scoring\Scoring.html
[generate-test-overview]    scoring\Spare.html
run.acceptance.tests:
```

**trimmed**

```
[junit] Implicitly adding C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\lib\junit-4.8.2.jar;C:\java\eclipse-helios\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\java\eclipse-helios\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant.jar;C:\java\eclipse-helios\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-junit.jar to CLASSPATH
    [junit] Using CLASSPATH C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\Bowling;C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\lib\junit-4.8.2.jar;C:\java\eclipse-helios\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\java\eclipse-helios\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant.jar;C:\java\eclipse-helios\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20100518-1145\lib\ant-junit.jar
    [junit] Running Overview
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec

BUILD FAILED
C:\Documents and Settings\gafitzgerald\training\Bowling\build.xml:31: Test Overview failed
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.actOnTestResult(JUnitTask.java:1840)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:837)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1785)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:785)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
```

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted your Ant file, so it's easier to read.

I noticed a few things:

- You don't have to *define* the JUnit task via a `<taskdef>`. The `<junit>` task is part of Ant. I think that's why you're getting: `[antlib:org.apache.tools.ant] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.`
- You need to compile your JUnit tests before you can run them. Is that `<generate-test-overview>` task doing that? Usually, when  you compile JUnit tests, you should include in the classpath:

  - All the jars you used when compiling.
  - The classes that you built that the JUnit tests will run.
  - The location of the `junit` jar (ant-junt.jar is already in the classpath).
- Fork JUnit tests when you run them. I don't know why `fork` is set to false, but JUnit tests should be forked.
- The `name` parameter of the `<test>` sub-entiity should be the name of the class you want to execute. I don't think `Overview` is it.
- Don't halt JUnit tests on failure. One test may fail, but others might have succeeded.